# MySQL how to use two different delimiters to import a txt file

Tags: mysql

I have a file containing around 94,000,000 lines, just like:

```
a,b c
e,f g
```

so i's delimiters is `,` and a blank. How should I do it? I have just studied to use one delimiters.

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
```

But there are two delimiters. My system is a Windows 10.

And what is more, the lengths of the b and f are different, so I can't use `@` to split it.

Comment: Are you planning on parsing a file with python to write into mysql database or reading the database?

Comment: You need To manipulate the data before presenting to mysql

Comment: I studied python,this file is too big to  manipulate by myself.it will be easy if i can use two delimiters =-=